Nuget Transitive Dependencies
I think I may have found the answer to my problem but I need confirmation. Basically, I need to override a transitive Nuget dependency that has a vulnerability. I upgraded the transitive dependency's version and it is now a direct dependency. This seems to be the fix according to this post and from Microsoft's documentation stating direct dependency wins. However, in the project file I still see a squiggly line. Is this IntelliSense acting up or is this not the fix?

